# printing a token that has certain number of character in python

Tags: python

I want to print a token that has certain character in a list.

For example,

```
list = ["cat","lion","elephant"]
```

and I want to print a token that has 4 character, which is lion.
How can I print a token that has only 4 character?

it should produce lion

Comment: You mean you want to find the one value in the list that has length 4?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't call your variable `list` since that name is already used by a built-in function.

As for your question, you can try using [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
>>> l = ["cat", "lion", "elephant"]
>>> 
>>> next(s for s in l if len(s) == 4)
'lion'
```

If you want all strings of length 4 as a list you can do something similar with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = ["cat", "lion", "elephant", "fish"]
>>> 
>>> [s for s in l if len(s) == 4]
['lion', 'fish']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in list:
    if len(x) == 4:
        print x
```

I recommend learning the basics of Python before asking questions that can easily be found already with a simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=find%20the%20length%20of%20a%20python%20string&oq=find%20the%20length%20of%20a%20python%20string&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5914j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8)

Be sure that in your real program you don't use `list` as your var name. It is already used in Python

Answer (score 0):

One way to print an item that has a specific amount of characters is to use a for loop. It allows you to iterate through a list.

Then you can use the length function to test if the item is equal to the amount of characters. If it is, then you can print it.

For example:

```
list = ["cat","lion","elephant"]

for i in list:
    if len(i) == 4:
        print i
```

Another way of doing this is to use list comprehensions, which outputs a list that you can print. This is useful if you have multiple items in the list that has 4 characters. You can then store it in a list for future use.

An example:

```
new_list = [x for x in list if len(x) == 4]
print new_list
```

Comment: It's `len()` (as opposed to `length()`).